# Is there are tool for Windows that notifies about and can kill long-running processes?

Tags: windows, process

Sometimes different scheduled tasks on different servers just stop working for no apparent reason (at least none I could clearly identify) and I would like to get notified about it via email and/or want the process get automatically killed.
The tool I'm searching for should run as a Windows service and I would like to specify the processes to look for via regular expressions which should be applied to the command lines of all running processes.

Comment: Sounds like any decent server/node monitoring suite ^^

Answer (score 1):

I've not heard of a program to do that, but when setting up a scheduled task you can go into the Settings tab, and set it to kill the task if it runs for more than X hours/days.

Comment: This is the right way. You can use the other tools in extremis.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a scheduled task with [taskkill](http://www.computerhope.com/taskkill.htm)

```
taskkill.exe /f /fi “status eq not responding”
```

But than off course you don't get any feedback on what it killed

Perhaps you can let a command echo you what programs are non-responding and email the echo to you.

Or check if [**VisualCron**](http://www.visualcron.com) can help do the job for you, it let's you set up scheduled tasks, also for killing tasks and notifies you in whichever way you want. With a simple GUI to setup the scheduled task. However I couldn't find if it also checks for tasks that are non-responding...

[image]

Though I suspect you're asking for a solution that will either require some coding from your side or simply doesn't exist...

Answer (score 0):

The SysinternalsSuite has a tool called [**`pslist.exe`**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682.aspx).

> **PsList** uses the Windows NT/2K performance counters to obtain the information it displays. You can find documentation for Windows NT/2K performance counters, including the source code to Windows NT's built-in performance monitor, PerfMon, in MSDN

**It can take a "`\\computer`" argument to fetch

process information from another machine on the network**.

Once you decide you want to kill a process, there is a similar tool, [**`pskill.exe`**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683.aspx).
This works on remote machines similarly.

---

*A long-running task is not necessarily stalled*.
You should analyze your tasks with the `pslist` command to identify stalled state.
These tools can then be used to kill such errant tasks remotely (from a single 'control' machine).

Both these tools are command line, allowing you to script from the control machine
(you just need remote access on the target machines).